AgGrid - Filter is not getting applied if applied immediately after data update
I am using ag grid and every 5 seconds I am updating the data using async Transaction. I have configured the filter in such a way that, when user clicks on Apply, then only filter needs to be applied on the UI.
I am facing two problems.
Problem 1: (Refer to Figure 1) On the grid, already a filter exist on Portfolio column with value as Defensive. Now I am interacting with the filter popup, I have selected new filter value=Aggressive, but not clicked on the Apply button. But grid is getting updated with the new selected filter values when the data gets updated in the background which I don't want. The filter should get applied only when user clicks on Apply button.
My solution: (Refer to Figure 2)To overcome this, I can store the grid filter model before the data update, and then reapply it after the transaction gets completed. But it introduces a new problem, i.e., on applying the existing filter, the Aggressive filter value gets automatically unselected after the data update (since it was not present on the filter model that I stored before the data update). This will definitely create a bad user experience.
Figure 1

Figure 2

Problem 2: (Refer to Figure 3) On the grid, already a filter exist on Portfolio column with value as Defensive. Now on the filter popup, I have selected a new filter value=Aggresive, and then if I click on Apply immediately after the transaction gets completed, the grid is not getting updated with the new filter, but the filter gets applied on the next data update. I am not able to find a solution for this.
Figure 3

Playground: https://plnkr.co/edit/6icyRM8qxg88LX18?open=index.jsx&preview
To see the code refer the above link.

